Inverse problems and chaos theory
In the classical theory of inverse problems we want to recover an unknown $u \in U$ from its noisy measurements $y \in L^2$, where $U$ is a Banach space. In particular, we study the following problem:
$$
\min_u \|\mathbf{L}(u)-y- \boldsymbol{n}\|_2^2+\alpha R(u),
$$
where $\mathbf{L}$ is the measurement linear operator that models the physics of the system, $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the noise, $\alpha$ is a well-chosen regularization parameter and $R$ is a general convex and $1$-positively homogenous regularizer. I want to ask if someone knows some papers or some other references that connect this problem to chaos theory. In particular, if it has been studied the previous problem with a regularizer arising from Bifurcation theory, Melnikov theory, exponential dichotomy or other theories or objects typical of chaos theory.
